# Debugging iPad's Safari on my PC

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari

I have developed games for web using HTML5, Javascript. Now I wanna to run these game on iPad as well. So I wanna debugging from iPad to my PC so that I can get information where game is getting stop functioning.

Please suggest me the way of debugging.

Thanks
Anil Neel

Answer (score 1):

You can debug on your Safari browser.

a. on iPad
   1. Go to Settings, Safari, Advanced and toggle Web Inspector on.
   2. Start your app or invoke your browser.

b. On PC and Mac
   1.  connect your iPad to your PC or Mac.
   2. Open Safari. 
   3. On Safari Preferences,Advanced, check "show develop menu..."
   4. you should see develop menu tab on Safari. Click and you an see a drop down with your iPad listed,
   5. Choose your game html from that list

happy debugging

Comment: In develop menu the iPad is not present.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Adobe Edge Inspect CC"

 https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-edge-inspect-cc/id498621426?mt=8

Comment: Any Body can tell other options.